# Swift UICollectionViewCell didSelectItemAt not printing label name on cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have looked through google and stack overflow and I was not able to find an answer. I have a UICollectionView and would like to take the user to another view upon the cell being clicked. But before doing so I would like to click the cell on the simulator and have the label's name printed in the console so I can from there figure out how to write the performSegue method. I am having issues with the didSelectItemAt function.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let clothesCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "clothesCell", for: indexPath) as! closetCollectionViewCell
    clothesCell.clothingName.text = shirtStyle[indexPath.item]
    clothesCell.clothingColor.text = shirtColor[indexPath.item]
    clothesCell.clothingSize.text = "\(sizes[indexPath.item])"

    return clothesCell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.item.clothingName)
}
```

Comment: Why is your data source in three separate arrays? You should have one array.

Comment: @rmaddy I should use a dictionary with string keys and values that are arrays right that would be more efficient?

Comment: A struct would be better than a dictionary. Then you create an array of that struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for print in didselectItem for selected items

```
print(shirtStyle[indexPath.item])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the cell that was clicked at indexPath like this:

```
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at:indexPath) as! closetCollectionViewCell
```

Then just get the values from the cell variables and print.

Comment: this gives the error Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'IndexPath'

Comment: @Ace Edited my answer. I forgot that cellForItem get IndexPath not an item.

Comment: This is not the correct solution. The cell does not contain the data, the data model contains the data. Please see the other answer for the proper solution.

Comment: @rmaddy read the question. topicstarter is asking about printing label from cell. if a cell is configured from data model, why not use that?

Comment: A cell is just a view. It's always better to get the actual data from the data model. The OP has no need to get the cell. They are confused about how to get the data properly. The other answer shows the proper way to access the data in the `didSelectItemAt` method.